# Link between the unique Id and the TermLabel of metadata

Tags: managed-metadata

I would like to ask a connection between the TermLabels and the associated unique id with that Label...my question is how find connection or link between the metadata applied or consumed to a documents and in which table of database do they available?...my requirement is that i need that particular table by which I can get the information of metadata applied to the particular documents..any help would be appreciated..

regards;

Comment: You want to find all documents that have a specific term associated?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for terms based on the term label using [TaxonomyClientService.GetTermsByLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.webservices.taxonomyclientservice.gettermsbylabel.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks for your response...i would like to ask about managed metadata services in SharePoint 2010,here I have created a service of managed metadata with some term sets in it,Now i have applied those metadata to the documents which i had uploaded on one of the sites...can you tel how the wss_content and managed metadata service is linked and where can i find the applied metadat in the wss_content database.?

please reply...

regards;

Comment: I suggest not going to database and look for the link. Only use supported API to access and modify content. However, the content field contains the value of the term text and GUID, in this format: "Customer A|ec8bd15f-5b37-4176-863e-d0da2ac7e9e3"

Comment: Thanks for the comment...May I ask you what are the supported API's for that and  link for the same from which I can get those API...it would be really a great help...